# Difference between each right and each

Tags: kdb

In KDB, why can I do this:

```
{[x;y]x+y} ./: enlist[(1;1);(2;1)]
```

but not this:

```
{[x]x+1} ./: enlist[1;2]
```

if i use this:

```
{[x]x+1} each enlist[1;2]
```

Then it works. Why would taking 2 params make a difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there a couple of things that need to be explained here, but not the difference between each and each-right.

Your first and second examples are not exactly comparable. With multiple arguments, `enlist` returns a single list so `enlist[(1;1);(2;1)]` returns a general list while `enlist[1;2]` returns a typed list (list of longs). More on `enlist` [here](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#enlist).

Now, one of the applications of the verb dot is *multi*-variate application, read [here](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#682-verb-dot). This means that it applies multiple arguments to a function and as such, `.` expects a list. Each-right takes each item of the right hand side in turn and passes it to the function on the left. Since `.` is expecting a list, but each item in your second line is an atomic long it throws a type error.

Updating the second line so that `.` receives a list as in your first line...

`q){[x]x+1} ./: enlist[(1;2)]
'rank`

This time we see a rank error as `.` tries to apply 2 arguments to the monadic function. Similarily;

`q){[x]x+1}[1;2]
'rank`

To fix this, we can further enlist. So that each-right passes 2, 1 item lists to `.` rather than 1, 2 item list.

`q){[x]x+1} ./: enlist each (1;2)
2 3`